# How to upload images to dropbox without install dropbox app in Android?

Tags: android, dropbox, dropbox-api

I want to upload the images in the background to the dropbox via my apps without install the dropbox app.

I also need the fast upload and security like I'm using dropbox to upload.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DropBox API can be the answer to your question.
 Check this [link](https://www.dropbox.com/developers) and [CoreAPI](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core) 
 You can use `DropboxAPI.UploadRequest` to upload your file. Use a service to do that in background.